# Unable to handle 404 error outside laravel and angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, .htaccess, laravel, http-status-code-404

I have a problem redirecting 404 errors to custom template.

My site structure is: project folder containing laravel and angularjs folders:

> -> Project
>
> ```
>  -> AngularTheme
>  -> Laravel
> ```

In my `.htaccess` I have redirected the requests coming from `/` to `/AngularTheme/index.php` which is working fine.

```
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ ./AngularTheme/index.php [L]
```

Now, when anyone type in anything after the `/` i.e `/foo` ***it throws 404 not found error to which I am not being able to handle***.

Inside laravel and Angular, there is not any problem redirecting to custome page.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I would stick to what you know to do this.

[here's a guide to do custom 404 handling in laravel](http://laravel.io/forum/10-23-2014-custom-404-in-laravel-42-with-layout)

Though you can also play around in angular with routing to go to a specific page in certain cases.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but this is not the solution, as I already mentioned that inside Laravel and AngularJS, I have no issue showing custom eror page.
But the problem is I have my root outside both.